# Show that $f(x)=1/x$ is a continuous function for any $x\neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

Following a reference from “Elementos de Topología general” by Angel Tamariz and Fidel Casarrubias.

> Let be $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and we choose $\epsilon>0$. We define $\delta=\min\left\{\frac{|a|}2,\frac{\epsilon|a|^2}2\right\}$ and so we observe that if $y\in B(a,\delta)$, then 
>   $$
> \left|\frac{1}y-\frac{1}a\right|=\frac{|y-a|}{|y||a|}\le\frac{2}{|a|^2}|y-a|<\frac{2}{|a|^2}\frac{|a|^2\epsilon}2=\epsilon
> $$
>
> and so we conclude that $\frac{1}x$ is continuous.

Unfortunately I don't understand why $\frac{|y-a|}{|y||a|}\le\frac{2}{|a|^2}|y-a|$, that is $\frac{1}{|y|}\le\frac{2}{|a|}$. In fact we have 
$$
|y-a|<\delta\le\frac{|a|}2\Rightarrow-2|a|<a-\frac{|a|}2<y<a+\frac{|a|}2<2|a|\Rightarrow|y|<2|a|\Rightarrow\frac{1}{|a|}<\frac{2}y
$$
that is in contradiction with $\frac{1}{|y|}\le\frac{2}{|a|}$.
Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\lvert y-a\rvert<\frac{\lvert a\rvert}2$, we have$$\lvert y\rvert\geqslant\bigl\lvert\lvert a\rvert-\lvert y-a\rvert\bigr\rvert=\lvert a\rvert-\lvert y-a\rvert>\frac{\lvert a\rvert}2.$$So$$\frac{\lvert y-a\rvert}{\lvert y\rvert\lvert a\rvert}<\frac{\lvert y-a\rvert}{\lvert a\rvert}\times\frac2{\lvert a\rvert}=\frac2{\lvert a\rvert^2}\lvert y-a\rvert.$$

Comment: Sorry, could you prove that $\lvert y\rvert\geqslant\bigl\lvert\lvert a\rvert-\lvert y-a\rvert\bigr\rvert=\lvert a\rvert-\lvert y-a\rvert>\frac{\lvert a\rvert}2$? Unfortunately it seems that it is difficult to me.

Comment: Note that$$\lvert a\rvert=\lvert a-y+y\rvert\leqslant\lvert a-y\rvert+\lvert y\rvert$$and that therefore $\lvert y\rvert\geqslant\lvert a\rvert-\lvert y-a\rvert$. Now, use the fact that $\lvert y-a\rvert<\frac{\lvert a\rvert}2$.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't succeed: I only see that $|y-a|<\frac{|a|}2<|a|\Rightarrow 0<|a|-|y-a|$. Could you explain, please?

Comment: Since $\lvert y-a\rvert<\frac{\lvert a\rvert}2$, then $\lvert a\rvert-\lvert y-a\rvert>\lvert a\rvert-\frac{\lvert a\rvert}2=\frac{\lvert a\rvert}2.$

Comment: Okay, now it is clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$ |a| = |y|\leq |a-y| < \delta < \frac{|a|}{2}$$

Thus

$$ |y| > \frac{|a|}{2}$$